# Which process is responsible for managing process management?

Tags: process, operating-system, multiprocessing, process-management

I was learning process management concept in operating system. Before that i came to know that processor can run one process at a time and to handle multiple processes we have process management.

At the very basic level process is just instance of program (code) and process management program is also code. Hence process management is itself a process.

So how come this process of process management program run along with other processes.

**Note : I am assuming that CPU can only run single process at a time**

Comment: The code responsible for process management (the kernel) doesn't have to be a process, and a process is usually more than just code. See this answer for some more infos: https://superuser.com/questions/197168/is-kernel-a-process

Comment: See [Wikipedia: Kernel (operating system)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)). Which OS are you familiar with?

Comment: Linux Newbie. Previously Windows.